# Boost spirit grammar match noisy input

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I am trying to parse a noisy input, ideally I would be able to see whether a stanza matchs the rule and if it does get the data I need and discard the rest.

The data I want is as follows.

```
Event: Newstate
Channel: SIP/104-000001bb
ChannelState: 6
ChannelStateDesc: Up
```

I want to make sure that Event if of type new state.

And I need the channel state. The rest I don't care about (just yet) so I want to ignore it, I want it to be flexible and accept any old crap bettween the important stuff, really i don't want to say ignore this line, but rather ignore anything between Event and the end of channel state where I capture the value.

So far I have got:

```
typedef boost::fusion::vector2<std::string, std::string> vect;
qi::rule<std::string::iterator, vect(), space> rule_ =
            lit("Event: ")      >> *char_("a-zA-Z") >>  
            qi::omit[ *char_ ]  >>  
            "ChannelState: "    >> *char_("0-9")    >>  
            qi::omit[ *char_ ];
```

but this isn't working for some reason, I always get false back when I do this:

```
vect v;
bool r=qi::parse(it, str.end(), rule_, v);
```

EDIT: Boost version 1.42 compiler g++ 4.4 Spirit 0x2020

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember: Spirit's parser is greedy. Which means that if you do `qi::omit[ <something> ]`, it will continue to omit characters until the `<something>` is no longer met. Since `<something>` is literally *anything* (`char_` matches any character, so `*char_` matches all characters), it will eat the entire rest of the string. Then it will raise an error, because it never got to "ChannelState: ".

Your way of doing it simply won't work. You have to have some cut-off switch to stop the `*char_` from eating everything.

I don't see why you don't just parse them all into a `std::map`, rather than doing it piecemeal. Then you can just pick out the elements you want. You say that you don't want some elements yet, so just ignore them.

This would be done as follows:

```
//Includes
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_pair.hpp>

//Code
using namespace boost::spirit;
using ascii::char_;
using ascii::string;

qi::rule<std::string::iterator, std::pair<std::string, std::string>() > pair_rule =
  *(char_ - ':') >> ':' >>
  qi::omit[*ascii::space] >>
  *(char_ - eol) >> (eol || eoi);

qi::rule<std::string::iterator, std::map<std::string, std::string>() > map_rule =
  +pair_rule;

std::map<std::string, std::string> v;
bool r = qi::parse(test.begin(), test.end(), map_rule, v);
```

Note that this works on Boost 1.47. I would suspect it would fail on earlier versions.

> Boost version 1.42 compiler g++ 4.4 Spirit 0x2020

Those are rather old. You should consider upgrading. Boost is up to 1.47 now.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I'll have to give it a whirl when I am back in work tomorrow. I know those versions are old, but I have to ensure it compile on the current debian version (squeeze) which forever lives in the past :(

Comment: @111111: Even if the `std::pair` and `std::map` stuff doesn't work on the older versions, you can always change the attribute to store a `std::vector` of a struct that holds two `std::string`s.

Comment: Yep, I was temped to do that anyway, seeing as there would be at most rarely more then 15 elements I would have thought that the overhead of a std::map would have been wasteful.